# Architecture of all the azure resources present in a subscription

Tags: azure, architecture

I need to get the architecture of all the resources connected in a subscription. Is there any feature where I can get the architecture of how all the resource are connected under a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

**In the Azure Portal, go to the Subscriptions and Select your Subscription**.

- Click on **Resource Groups** or **Resources** based on your need.

[image]

**Resource Groups** option shows you the resource groups using these filters like Location, Type, Kind, Resource Group, etc.

[image]

**Resources** Option shows you all the resources based on its recent activity.
But you can get the resources which are linked with that resource group or specific Azure Services using the **filters** option.

For example,

- In Resource Groups Page, if you select **`No grouping`** option - it shows all the resource groups alphabetically/randomly.
- If you select the **filter** as type, then it shows the resource groups according to services like:

[image]